# How to integrate spring-security.xml file into spring boot ? using Annotation base only

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

*I have searched and didn't find any helpful solution that's why i am going to post this question.*

Actually i have `spring boot` project which is completely configure based upon '`Annotation`'.

Now for some reason, i need to add `spring-security` into this `project`. 
for that i am getting `spring-security-XXX.xml` file from other `co-worker`.

Now, i am thinking how can i wrote some `Annotation` which will **automatically** load that `spring-serity-xxx.xml` file into my current project  environment without change any other part, so that i can achieve security feature as per `spring-serity-xxx.xml` file.

For example, `@Configuration(classpath:spring-security-config.xml)` something like, is it possible ?.

if it's possible then provide me completed `list of configuration`.

**NOTE** : *security added to get OAuth integration.*

*Any Help Appreciate..!!*

Answer (score 1):

Use [`@ImportResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining-java-centric) annotation.